# Visual studio code auto import does not work for newly created typescript (~3.9.6) files (angular project)

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Whenever I create a new component or service, be it generated by angular CLI, or created manually, visual studio code won't find the class for auto import. I have to do it manually and afterwards it starts working. This functionality used to work few months back, I'm just wondering if there is any solution for this.